# OAuth Authentication schedule in Task scheduler

Tags: c#, google-api

OAuth authentication for google analytics data is not working when I schedule this in task scheduler. It's giving below error and it's woking fine when I run exe manually:

> Daimto.Google.Sample.Analytics.DaimtoAnalyticsAuthenticationHelper - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
>   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59
>   Daimto.Google.Sample.Analytics.Program - end calling AuthenticateOauth

Comment: *access is denied* You need to configure that task to run as a normal user, not under the system account.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working now.

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)